# Run Validation before @HandleBeforeCreate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm having some problem with validation with Spring Rest, the @HandleBeforeCreate event handler is running before the validation. I was expecting it to run after the validation.

In my test application I have a transaction, which has two fields to store the transaction value, one for the real transaction currency and another for the final value converted to the user currency. In my handle before create I'm dealing with that conversion, but I want the request to stop in the validator if the amount is null.

I could validate the resource in the event handler (I'm ready to handle a RepositoryConstraintViolationException), but it make me think on the point of using validator. It also seams a little inefficient that on every data rest request, spring loop through all validator checking if they support the object class.

Is validation on EventHandlers preferable than Validators (for performance reasons)? How can I force validator to run before EventHandlers?

*I'm using spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE

> Validator

```
public class TransactionValidator extends SpringValidator<Transaction> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Transaction.class.equals(clazz) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void validateObject(Transaction transaction, Errors errors) {
        ... validations ...
    }

}


public abstract class SpringValidator<T> implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        validateObject((T) target, errors);
    }

    protected abstract void validateObject(T target, Errors errors);

}
```

> Event Handler

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RepositoryEventHandler(Transaction.class)
public class TransacationEventHandler {

    private final CurrencyUnitService currencyUnitService;

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void beforeCreate(Transaction transaction) {
        adjustTransactionAmount(transaction);
    }

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void beforeSave(Transaction transaction) {
        adjustTransactionAmount(transaction);
    }

}
```

### Edit

I checked the source code and the listeners are invoked in the following order:

[image]

Which make sense actually, using a BeforeCreateHandler is the only way to fix/change something in the Entity before running the Validator. I'm 100% open to inputs.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Hello @masT, I don't remeber exactly how I set stuff up, but you can throw a RepositoryConstraintViolationException anywhere in your controller/event handler code that will have the same effect of a Validator

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Use @Validated (did not test it)

You could do this:

```
@HandleBeforeCreate
public void beforeCreate(@Validated Transaction transaction) {
    adjustTransactionAmount(transaction);
}
```

## 2. Otherwise - you may define the `Validator` through Java Configuration

You may follow this answer from **@MathiasDpunkt** ([Spring data rest validation + exception mapper: confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437823/spring-data-rest-validation-exception-mapper-confusing)):

> ```
> @Configuration
> public class MyValidationConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
>
>     @Bean
>     @Primary
>     /**
>      * Create a validator to use in bean validation - primary to be able to autowire without qualifier
>      */
>     Validator validator() {
>         return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener
> validatingListener) {
>         Validator validator = validator();
>         //bean validation always before save and create
>         validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
>         validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't solve the "validator running before the handler" issue, but it helped me to undestand how to use bean hibernate bean validation.

Comment: @RafaelTeles did you ever got it working?